Cisco Phone XML timezone baghdad time error
I'm trying to edit the configuration of cisco cp-7821 cnf.xml file to make the timezone for Asia/Baghdad, but to no avail, the code is below:
  <dateTimeSetting> 
     <dateTemplate>D/M/YA</dateTemplate> 
     <timeZone>Arabia Standard Time</timeZone>
     <ntps> 
        <ntp> 
           <name>pool.ntp.org</name>
           <ntpMode>Unicast</ntpMode> 
        </ntp>         
     </ntps> 
  </dateTimeSetting>

I also have an NTP server with IP address 192.168.50.1
how do I set the phone to take time settings directly either by ntp.org or the NTP server I have configured?
I have tried GMT+3, Asia/Baghdad, Arabian, Arabia.. etc, but it didn't work it always uses GMT time.

Can you change it using the phone menu?  You can then open the xml file and check the correct value.

no I can't from the phone menu, kind of limited functionalities in the cp-7821 screen

You may need to change the version of firmware in the phone.  See https://community.cisco.com/t5/ip-telephony-and-phones/cp-7821-showing-incorrect-timeing/td-p/2632710
